# FragmentStatePagerAdapter only charge page current

Tags: android, caching, android-viewpager, fragment, fragmentstatepageradapter

When using FragmentStatePagerAdapter "This is better for pagination through a collection of objects for the number of pages is undefined. Destroy fragments as the user navigates to other pages, which minimizes memory usage"
[

This FragmentStatePagerAdapter works as follows, when you load the 0 position for the first time, what it does is loads
Page 0 and page 1 if you turn to page 1, page 3 is loaded and if afterwards (after creating a base of the current position).
If I go to the back tab of the actual position no load the data again, if it caches the view, my problem
In this behavior it seems that the left and right views of the real view are cached, there is some sort of
Omit this behavior

The answers you found in stackOverflow have not been clear, find an option of Internet access where to mention modifying this class
FragmentStatePagerAdapter inherits PageAdapter, I have not solved this problem for 5 days, please if someone can help me explain how I can solve it, I will be infinitely happy.
Custom class that supposedly clears the FragmentStatePagerAdapter cache
[

//getItem it does not work the way you expect (just inflate the current fragment)
Custom class that supposedly clears the FragmentStatePagerAdapter cache

```
public class CostumAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        public CostumAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);

        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            System.out.println("POSICION: "+position);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            FragmentBebidas fragmentBebidas = new FragmentBebidas();
            bundle.putInt("ID", Integer.parseInt(listMenu.get(position).getId()));
            fragmentBebidas.setArguments(bundle);

            return fragmentBebidas;

        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return menuTabs.get(position).toString();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return menuTabs.size();
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
            return POSITION_NONE;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            super.destroyItem(container, position, object);

        }
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Doesn't clear what you want!

Comment: It is that the back tab of the selected position is cached and if I return, the tab data will no longer work. I just want to update the data of the selected tab currently Tab, but only that of not the others, so susecientemente with each tab @ Kishore Jethava

Answer (score 0):

There is a work around to this, you can use the `FragmentManager` to retain the fragments that were created by the `ViewPager`.

Extend this `abstract` class

```
public abstract class StateSaveFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public FragmentManager fragmentManager;

    public StateSaveFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
        this.fragmentManager = fragmentManager;
    }

    public abstract int viewPagerId();

    public Fragment getSavedFragment(int position) {
        return fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(frameworkFragmentName(viewPagerId(),
                getItemId(position)));
    }

    private String frameworkFragmentName(int viewId, long id) {
        return "android:switcher:" + viewId + ":" + id;
    }
}
```

Your adapter should look something like this:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends StateSaveFragmentAdapter {

    public ProjectDetailFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
    }

    @Override
    public int viewPagerId() {
    // your viewpager id
        return R.id.pager;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    // check if fragment was saved
        if (getSavedFragment(position) != null) 
        return getSavedFragment(position);

    // if save fragment was null, continue with normal implementation           
    FragmentBebidas fragmentBebidas = new FragmentBebidas();
        bundle.putInt("ID", Integer.parseInt(listMenu.get(position).getId()));
        fragmentBebidas.setArguments(bundle);
    return fragmentBebidas;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
    // your implementation
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        // your implementation
    }
}
```

Comment: But it does not want to save the state of the previous ones, I only want the one of the selected fragment, possibly and there is a confusion with the second image,
I just want to load the selected the other fragments not, I just want to be loading the selected page and so with each one only the selected one. I explain

Comment: The behavior remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

@Isa M I suppose you require to refresh the data of particular fragment which is visible to user. For that purpose you can use method setUserVisibleHint(). In that a boolean variable lets you know if the fragment is visible to user.
If it is do your required code in that block.

Comment: You have a snippet of that code from your idea to solve, which is very grateful

Comment: Here is the code :

@Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if (isVisibleToUser) {
            //do your work here
        } 
    }